# Android: Set Background Color State List to ListActivitiy

Tags: android, colors, android-listview

I habe a Activity which `extends ListActivity`.

The ListView uses colors from the default theme. How can I set my own Color State List Resource to the ListView?

I tried this in `onCreate()`:

```
getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_listview);
```

this is background_listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

but i get only errors

```
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag
requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create your own `Adapter`, but swap out `android:color` for `android:drawable` in the selector and make sure you set it using the correct method.

- [`setSelector(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelector%28int%29)

So don't set the selector as background to the `ListView`, but rather supply it as follows in order for the resource to work on the items in the `ListView`:

```
getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.background_listview);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your own custom adapter that will be extended from ListAdapter and in overrided getView() method inflate your custom layout for each list's item. In this layout you should set your selector as background. Actually your selector looks ok.

**UDPATE :**

look at this simple code :

**Activity:**

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExampleObject> listObjects;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_listview);
        listObjects = new ArrayList<ExampleObjects>();
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, listObjects);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ExampleObject> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public NoteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<ExampleObject> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
}
```

**Your list_item.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/your_selector">

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope, it will helpful for you. And may be I made mistakes, because I wrote code w/o compiller.

**UPDATE AGAIN :**

For your situation change `android:color="#ff000000"` to `android:drawable="#ff000000"`. It will help I hope.

Good luck!

Comment: I have a SimpleAdapter and a ViewBinder. Does this fit together?

Comment: When you use ListActivity, you use standart adapter and standart listView. If you want to customize your list, you should use simaple Activity and create your custom adapter. I will update my answer and show you simple code. Wait please.

Comment: I already have a list_item.xml for my SimpleAdapter. I changed it to <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_listview"
    android:orientation="horizontal" > but I got the same error message again: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown> ...Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background_listview.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020006 -

Comment: resource exits otherwise it would not compile

Comment: try change color to drawable in your selector

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22077/discussion-between-ilya-demidov-and-user1324936)